# Iterate over each div and get its html contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery I wish to iterate over every div and display its contents. So far as I have written it I get the error "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"

```
$.each( $("div.autocomplete-suggestions > .autocomplete-suggestion").html(), function() {

    console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over elements and not on their contents. use:

```
$("div.autocomplete-suggestions > .autocomplete-suggestion").each(function(){
     console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this-

```
$("div.autocomplete-suggestions > .autocomplete-suggestion").each(function(){
 console.log($(this).html());
})
```